# Validation in Yii

Tags: yii

Can one validation rules be shared for `Edit` and `Create` pages?

For example, when creating a photo album, you must provide a name and select an image (the cover of that album). And then a form is serialized. Suppose a form looks like as,

```
<form>

   <input type="text" name="name"/> 

   <br />

   <input type="file" name="cover" /> 

</form>
```

Again : A field `name` cannot be blank and an image should be selected in `cover`

But what about `Edit` page?
Here name is a must, but `cover` isn't (because user might leave it blank in order to to override an existing cover)!

Can this be done by default in Yii?

Answer (score 2):

If you want different validation for edit and Insert, You can set in model `rules` as below

```
array('name', 'required', 'on'=>'create'),
```

Reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios

Comment: No, no no, I want the same validator for both edit and create forms (As they will have a lot of fields in real world scenario - name, gender, country etc...) **BUT** on edit form, an image is not required, while on create form is required

Comment: then post your `rules` function to fix.

Comment: Without the `'on'=>'create'` the rule will be used for all scenarios. Alternatively a rule with `'on'=>'create,update'` only applies for create or update.

Comment: @topher Yes you are correct. For image, we need to do validation in different way. But djay need to show his code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the  rule with scenario for creating, only for name:

```
array('name', 'required', 'on'=>'create'),
```

If your other fields (gender, country...) aren't related to any scenario then they will be applied also in 'create' scenario.

```
 array('gender', 'required'),
```

Use $model->setScenario('create') on creating action.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple scenarios for a rule :

array($attributes,$validation,'on'=>'update,insert')

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios